# Ordered Logit in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm interested in running an ordered logit regression in python (using pandas, numpy, sklearn, or something that ecosystem). But I cannot find any way to do this. Is my google-skill lacking? Or is this not something that's been implemented in a standard package?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/fabianp/minirank/blob/master/minirank/logistic.py)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:
Logit and Probit Ordinal regression models are now built in to statsmodels.

https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/ordinal_regression.html

```
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel
```

Examples are given in the documentation above.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.miscmodels.ordinal_model import OrderedModel
url = "https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/ologit.dta"
data_student = pd.read_stata(url)

mod_log = OrderedModel(data_student['apply'],
                        data_student[['pared', 'public', 'gpa']],
                        distr='logit')

res_log = mod_log.fit(method='bfgs', disp=False)
res_log.summary()
```

The catch is that the development version of `statsmodels` is far ahead of the release.  They say that installing the dev version of `statsmodels` is okay for everyday use. So I used the following:

```
pip3 install git+git@github.com:statsmodels/statsmodels.git
```

to do so.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for Ordered Logistic Regression, it looks like you can find it in [Fabian Pedregosa's `minirank` repo on GitHub](https://github.com/fabianp/minirank/blob/master/minirank/logistic.py).

(Hattip to @elyase, who originally provided the link in a comment on the question.)

Comment: The project has moved to https://github.com/fabianp/mord with an updated `scikit-learn` like API