# Seaborn error while visualizing bag of words

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bag

I was given this tip in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271368/regression-model-pandas?noredirect=1#51273930) SO question I asked:

> Now that you have your matrix representation (rows are the products,
>   columns are the counts for each unique word), you can filter the
>   matrix down to the most common words. I would encourage you to take a
>   look at how the distribution of word counts looks. We will use seaborn
>   for that and import it like so:
>
> `import seaborn as sns`
>
> Given that your pd.DataFrame holding the word-count matrix is called
>   df, `sns.distplot(df.sum())` should do the trick. Choose some cutoff
>   that seems like it preserves a good chunk of the counts but doesn't
>   include many words with low counts. It can be arbitrary and it doesn't
>   really matter for now. Your word count matrix is your input data, or
>   also called the predictor variable. In machine learning this is often
>   called the input matrix or vector `X`.

I managed to do the bag of words (BOG) for every column. The code is as follows:

```
df['BOW'] = df.Review2.str.split().apply(Counter)
```

But when I try to visualize as suggested (`sns.distplot(df['BOW'].sum())`) I get the following error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Counter' and 'int'

Thx for reading the post and have a good day :)

Comment: What does `df.Review2` contain. Could you provide an example, see [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added an edit to it