# Panel ordered logit in Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression, glm, panel-data

I am looking to run a panel ordered logit model on Python. I am aware that this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035216/ordered-logit-in-python), however, this is not for panel data. What I am looking for is something equivalent to the "[pglm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pglm/pglm.pdf)" R package. Is there a library for this on Python?

Comment: You need to elaborate your questions for better answers. Short answer is No equivalent to pglm